# Firefox 57+ legacy extensions nuked: how can I obtain multiple tab rows (which TabMixPlus enabled)

Tags: firefox

I am thinking maybe editing the prefs.js file?  See post [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/113147/108624) for why. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Although this question is off-topic on SO, it is a valid one: where to migrate this Q to? The loss of TabMix greatly reduces the effectiveness of the Firefox tab bar. For a solution, I am thinking along the lines of [userChrome.css](https://www.userchrome.org/what-is-userchrome-css.html), but I haven't yet figured out exactly how...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It is not the same as Tab Mix and lacks a whole bunch of usefulness, but it does put the tabs on multiple rows.

First, **locate your profile directory** (see e.g. [Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Profiles)), mine is at

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxxxx.default
```

(where `xxxxxxxx` is some random characters), on a typical Linux system.

If it does not exist yet, create a subfolder `chrome` and within that a file `userChrome.css` (I think the capitalization of the filename does matter, but I did not test that):

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxxxx.default/chrome/userChrome.css
```

In **`userChrome.css`, add the following code**, which I got from [this source](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/6yvi2j/yet_another_collection_of_addons_to_imitate_tab/dmrniao/?context=1):

```
.tabbrowser-tab {
    flex-grow:1;
    min-width:150px;
}
.tabbrowser-tab,.tab-background {
    height:29px;
}
.tab-stack {
    width: 100%;
}
.tabbrowser-tabs .scrollbox-innerbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.tabbrowser-tabs .arrowscrollbox-scrollbox {
    overflow: visible;
    display: block;
}
.tabbrowser-tabs .scrollbutton-up,.tabbrowser-tabs .scrollbutton-down,#alltabs-button{
    display: none;
}
```

After saving, you need to **restart Firefox**.

---

**Bonus**: another nice feature that Tab Mix brought, is the placement of a close button on each separate tab. This can be done by adding another piece of code to the same file (from [this source](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/6wiu9k/is_there_a_webextension_for_multiple_rows_of_tabs/))

```
.tab-close-button:not([pinned="true"]) {
    display: -moz-box !important;
}
```